# Why isn't ngInfiniteScroll working for tables?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, infinite-scroll, nginfinitescroll

I am trying to implement ngInfiniteScroll on my table with ng-repeat on `<tbody>` However, it doesn't get triggered when I reach the end of page.

```
<div infinite-scroll="list.getMoreItems()">
    <table md-table md-row-select>
        <thead md-head>
           <tr md-row>
                <th md-column><span>Id</span></th>
                <th md-column><span>Item</span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
       <tbody md-body ng-repeat="data in list.items">
           <tr md-row><td md-cell>{{data.title}}</td></tr>
           <tr md-row><td md-cell>Click here </td></tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

My `getMoreItems()` does nothing more than throw an alert for now.

ngInfiniteScroll is configured correctly as it does execute `getMoreItems()` on page load but never after that.

Comment: can you show you infinit-scroll directive codeso i can help you ?

Comment: @ManojPatidar I haven't made this directive. I am using an external package - https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/

Comment: It looks like you are missing `infinite-scroll-distance` (i.e. `infinite-scroll-distance="3"`)

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah [The docs](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/documentation.html) says that's optional. `infinite-scroll-distance (optional)`

Comment: @AkshayKhetrapal Please can you post the Controller code along with any other parts wherever `list` is defined and used. Are you using "Controller As" syntax? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the viewport to scroll calculation. Removing `overflow-y:hidden` from the container that contains ng-repeat solved the problem.

```
<div id="holdList" infinite-scroll="list.getMoreItems()">
    <table md-table md-row-select>
        <thead md-head>
           <tr md-row>
                <th md-column><span>Id</span></th>
                <th md-column><span>Item</span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
       <tbody md-body ng-repeat="data in list.items">
           <tr md-row><td md-cell>{{data.title}}</td></tr>
           <tr md-row><td md-cell>Click here </td></tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
</div>


#holdList
{
   height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML:

```
<tbody md-body ng-repeat="data in list.items | limitTo:barLimit">
```

And within your `getMoreItems()` method:

```
$scope.barLimit = 100;
$scope.getMoreItems = function () {
    $scope.barLimit += 50;
}
```

Based on this [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/12096/)

Comment: That... doesn't solve my problem, Matthew. 
I've mentioned above, `getMoreItems()` doesn't really get triggered.